# Which of these two Vuetify Navigation Drawer prevent prop mutation workarounds seem better?

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, vue.js

I am very new to **Vue.js**, I just stumbled on a very hard thing to do (at least for me) where Vue was complaining about mutating a prop (children shouldn't change parent props apparently). I was about to give up at 8~ hour mark, but then it worked! Then not only that, I came with another solution. Here are the two solutions:

Using `watch`:

```
const VueNavDrawerComp={
    props : ["childSideNav", "menuItems"],
    template : 
    /*html*/
    `
    <div>
        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="otherVar" absolute temporary>
            ...
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </div>
    `,
    data(){
        return {
            otherVar : this.childSideNav
        };
    },
    watch : {
        childSideNav : function(newValue){
            this.otherVar=newValue;
        },
        otherVar : function(newValue){
            if(!newValue){
                this.$emit("ev-toggle-drawer");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Using `computed`:

```
const VueNavDrawerComp={
    props : ["childSideNav", "menuItems"],
    template : 
    /*html*/
    `
    <div>
        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="computedSideNav" absolute temporary>
            ...
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </div>
    `,
    data(){
        return {};
    },
    computed : {
        computedSideNav : {
            get(){
                return this.childSideNav;
            },
            set(newValue){
                if(!newValue){
                    this.$emit("ev-toggle-drawer");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Anyway, I fiddled around with some console logs, to try to see if things were firing the correct amount of times, and things like that, but I have no idea to how to find out which of the two is more optimized or have better "code taste" as the Linux guy would say.

Anyone experienced **Vue.js** can enlighten me in which is better option or if some corrections/improvements can be done?.

To clarify a bit, `v-navigation-drawer` is a **Vuetify** component. A Boolean is passed to affect the visibility of the Drawer. When the event listener is executed, it will toggle a common shared Boolean across more components and this Boolean must be in sync with all of them.

Comment: Is `v-navigation-drawer` a component from Vuetify? What kind of property is `childSideNav`? When the event is emitted, what does the parent do about it? What happens exactly?

Comment: @SimonForsberg yes component of Vuetify (did not find a tag in this site), a Boolean is passed to show or hide the Drawer, the event toggles the Boolean to hide it. There are other components that can also toggle the visibility of the Drawer (like the collapsed menu button in mobile) and they all must share a commun Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One-Way Data Flow

> *(children shouldn't change parent props apparently)*

Yes- this is explained in the documentation section for [**Components In-Depth** > Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

> #### [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)
>
> All props form a **one-way-down binding** between the child property and
> the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to
> the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child
> components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can
> make your app’s data flow harder to understand.
>
> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in
> the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This
> means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child
> component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

---

### Computed properties vs. watchers

> *Anyone experienced **Vue.js** can enlighten me in which is better option or if some corrections/improvements can be done?*

The [documentation for Computed caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) contains this fragment:

> ... **computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies**. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.

If `computed` can be used instead of `watch` then it is the better option for that reason.

---

#### whitespace

The usage of whitespace doesn't match much of the idiomatic JavaScript I have seen - e.g.

> ```
> const VueNavDrawerComp={
> ```

most style guides (e.g. [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-whitespace), [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace)) recommend a space on either side of operators like `=`

> ```
> watch : {
> ```

The space following the colon is typical but not the space before. Even [the examples in the VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering) follow this pattern.